# Is the series absolut convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to solve the two following expressions for absolut convergent series:

1.$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{sin\cdot n}{n(n+1)}$$

2.$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{n}\sqrt{n}$$

For the 1., I would say because the numerator is bounded and the denominator converges to $0$ the first series seems absolut convergent.

For the 2., I would say it diverges. After plugging some numbers into $n^{1/n}$ the sequence converges to $1$. However the series diverge to ${\infty}$ . Is it correct?

Comment: For 1. is n=0 or it takes `1` first?

Comment: For 1, your arguments are true, but the conclusion is false. Just note that $|\sin n|/[n(n+1)]<n^{-2}$.

Comment: @Brandon: I think you mean that the claims are true (mostly, since the denominator actually grows without bound), as is the conclusion, but the conclusion doesn't actually follow from the claims, so the argument is invalid. To Googi: Consider the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$$ to see why your argument in the first part does not work.

Comment: hm. I dont get it.

Comment: I just had to make a comparison? 1.$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{sin\cdot n}{n(n+1)}$$ $<$ $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the first one is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin n}{n(n+1)}$ it converges absolutely, e.g. by comparison with the convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$.

The second one, no matter whether it is meant to be $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\sqrt{n}$ or $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{1/n}$, clearly diverges to $\infty$, since the partial sum of the first $n$ terms is larger than $n$.

Comment: So basically what I have to do when determining the convergence or absolut convergence is just to make a comparison between the series under consideration and a already known series ..harmonic, geometric and so on

Comment: This is one approach. Alternatively, you can use one of the various convergence tests, such as Leibniz test, Integral test, Ratio test, Root criterium, ..

Comment: @ALL thank you for the illustrating examples

Comment: @Googi Please accept one of the answers, if the question is cleared for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the second series is $\sum \sqrt[n]{n}$ then it is divergent becouse $\sqrt[n]{n} \to 1$.

The first one is absolutly convergent because $\left|\frac{\sin n}{n(n+1)}\right| \le \frac{1}{n^{2}}$